# Passing PNG file request to PHP scrpt in Nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Here is what I need to do - I need my server to serve up two versions of a set of images.  The first set of images are real PNG files that sit in a folder on my server, call it `/realimages`.  The second set of images do not actually exist.  When they are requested I want to take the requested image file name e.g.

```
https://example.com/nosuchimage/img1.png
```

generate the image via the index.php script sitting inside the `/nosuchmage` folder (or elsewhere if easier).

That script does the following

- Picks up a related image from the `/realimages` folder
- Uses PHP GD to generate a background
- Superimposes the related image on the background
- serves up the result

That script has been written and is fully functional.  What I do not know is how to force all PNG image requests to the `/nosuchimage` folder to be redirected to that script with the original request passed as a script parameterr.

I know that doing this a relatively trivial configuration issue with NGINX which involves writing a rewrite rule.  However, NGINX rewriting is still quite a black art to me.  Hopefully, someone here will be able to tell me just what that rewrite rule should be.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect all the images of a certain folder, just use the code below in your configuration file.

In my case I will use the default file.
`/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

```
location ~ \/realimages/(.+\.png)$ {
    return 302 $scheme://$server_name/nosuchimage/$1;
}

// Access: http://www.example.com/images/valdeirpsr.png (Exists & Redirect to /nosuchimage/valdeirpsr.png)
// Access: http://www.example.com/images/valdeirpsr2.png (Not Exists & Redirect to /nosuchimage/valdeirpsr2.png)
```

To redirect only the images not found in a particular folder, just use the code below in your configuration file.

```
location ~ \/realimages/(.+\.png)$ {
    error_page 404 $scheme://$server_name/nosuchimage/$1;
}

// Access: http://www.example.com/images/valdeirpsr.png (Exists & Show Image)
// Access: http://www.example.com/images/valdeirpsr2.png (Not Exists & Redirect to /nosuchimage/valdeirpsr2.png)
```